# onFailure : Failed to invoke public okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am having the above error in my code due to which onFailure is getting called, i tried everything but could not fix it. I am trying to send an image to the server using retrofit2. Been banging my head for a couple of hours now. Also please explain your answer..........

Here is my code:

```
package com.time.employeelogin;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.database.annotations.NotNull;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import id.zelory.compressor.Compressor;
import mumayank.com.airlocationlibrary.AirLocation;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Selfie extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AirLocation airLocation;
    public static final String TAG = "SelfieAct";
    private static final int REQUEST = 1856;
    private TextView Time, location;
    Button time_stamp, lcn_btn, Atten_btn;
    private static final String TIME_STAMP = null;
    NetworkController networkController;
    private Button cptrm_btn;
    private ImageView imgview;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    Bitmap lesimg;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String locationText;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    File photoFile;
    boolean facelocationset = false;
    TextView textView;
    Uri photoUri;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selfie_activity);

        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });


        networkController = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(NetworkController.class);if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            if (!hasPermissions(Selfie.this, PERMISSIONS)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow location permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Selfie.this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
            } else {
                //do here
            }
        } else {
            //do here
        }

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot Continue Without Location Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        Time = findViewById(R.id.time);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.prefs), MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.prefs), MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        Atten_btn = findViewById(R.id.mark_Attendence);


        cptrm_btn = findViewById(R.id.cptr_btn);
        imgview = findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.Waitmsg);

        airLocation = new AirLocation(this, true, true, new AirLocation.Callbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NotNull Location location) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Selfie.this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                locationText = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                textView.setText(locationText);
                facelocationset = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(@NotNull AirLocation.LocationFailedEnum locationFailedEnum) {
                // do something
            }
        });

        cptrm_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                cameraIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);



                if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {



                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + ex.getMessage());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + ex.toString());
                    }
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {

                        photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Selfie.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        Atten_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(facelocationset && mImageBitmap != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(Selfie.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                    Date dt = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMddHHmmss");

                    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(
                                    MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(Selfie.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile))),
                                    photoFile
                            );
                    MultipartBody.Part body =
                            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", photoFile.getName(), requestFile);
                    MultipartBody.Part io_time =
                            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("io_time", df.format(dt));
                    MultipartBody.Part user_id =
                            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("user_id", prefs.getString("uid", null));
                    MultipartBody.Part loc =
                            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("loc", locationText);

                    RequestBody enctype = RequestBody.create(
                            okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, "multipart/form-data");


                    networkController.mark_attendance("Bearer " + prefs.getString("token", null), enctype, body, io_time, user_id, loc).enqueue(new Callback<RequestBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<RequestBody> call, Response<RequestBody> response) {
                            if (response.code() == 200) {
                                Toast.makeText(Selfie.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();



                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<RequestBody> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getLocalizedMessage() + t.getCause());
                        }
                    });

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Selfie.this, "Waiting for Location or Image" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            }
        });


    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        airLocation.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                InputStream ims = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
                mImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Bitmap mImageDisplayBitmap = handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(getApplicationContext(), photoUri);
                imgview.setImageBitmap(mImageDisplayBitmap);
            }
            catch (IOException io){}
            File file = new File (String.valueOf(photoFile));
            try {
                mImageBitmap = new Compressor(this)
                        .setMaxHeight(200) //Set height and width
                        .setMaxWidth(200)
                        .setQuality(100) // Set Quality
                        .compressToBitmap(photoFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                mImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException f){}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        airLocation.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Selfie.this, "The app was not allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
            throws IOException {
        int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
        int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
        imageStream.close();

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

        img = rotateImageIfRequired(context, img, selectedImage);
        return img;
    }

    private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                             int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
            // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

            // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
            // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
            // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
            // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
            // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

            final float totalPixels = width * height;

            // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
            final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize++;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context, Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

        InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        ExifInterface ei;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
            ei = new ExifInterface(input);
        else
            ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());

        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotateImage(img, 90);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotateImage(img, 180);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotateImage(img, 270);
            default:
                return img;
        }
    }

    private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        img.recycle();
        return rotatedImg;
    }

}
```

My networkcontroller

```
   @Multipart
    @POST("employee/manual_punch")
    Call<RequestBody> mark_attendance(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Part("enctype") RequestBody enctype, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part MultipartBody.Part io_time, @Part MultipartBody.Part user_id, @Part MultipartBody.Part loc);
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
2019-07-26 14:13:19.949 18276-18276/com.time.employeelogin D/SelfieAct: onFailure: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:113)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class okhttp3.RequestBody
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212) 
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39) 
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27) 
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223) 
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace. Put t.printStackTrace() in onFailure().

Comment: https://del.dog/tufejiyipu.sh

Comment: What is the model that you made for the response? The call should be Call<ResponseModel>(the model you create) not Call<ResponseBody>.

Comment: Thanks man, my bad

Comment: Did you solve your problem? if yes please accept my answer so that it may help someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call should be `Call<ResponseModel>` (the model you create) not `Call<ResponseBody>.`

Comment: can't find ResponseModel